# Pandas what kind of merge, join, or concat for multindex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have dataframe with multindex:

```
     A | B
1 0  a   b
2 0  c   d
  1  e   f
3 0  g   h
  1  i   j
  2  k   l
```

I also have a series with a matching index level 0

```
1 m
2 n
3 o
```

Now, I would like to add values form this series to the dataframe

```
     A | B | C
1 0  a   b   m
2 0  c   d   n
  1  e   f   n
3 0  g   h   o
  1  i   j   o
  2  k   l   o
```

What kind of join, merge, concat should I use?
I don't mind if i have to ffill afterwards but I would like to keep the dataframe's mulitindex intact.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your index levels, so you can reference them in the merge. Also convert your `Series` to a `DataFrame`:

```
df.index.names=['idx1', 'idx2']
df.merge(s.to_frame('C'), left_on='idx1', right_index=True)

           A  B  C
idx1 idx2         
1    0     a  b  m
2    0     c  d  n
     1     e  f  n
3    0     g  h  o
     1     i  j  o
     2     k  l  o
```

---

Also possible to remove one of the index levels, then join the `Series` and add the index level back:

```
df.reset_index(1).join(s.rename('C')).set_index('level_1', append=True)

           A  B  C
  level_1         
1 0        a  b  m
2 0        c  d  n
  1        e  f  n
3 0        g  h  o
  1        i  j  o
  2        k  l  o
```

Comment: Excellent. The key here is to make sure indexes have the same name. Then it works with dataframe.join(series)